horizontal space in Table of Contents
I have an issue with the TOC. As you can see there's no space between the number and the subsection-names when the numbers get more than 1 digit. Is there an easy command to change the spacing?

it get worse with this code
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{10} %use to adjust chapter number incase you don't include certain chapters
\setcounter{section}{10}
\setcounter{subsection}{10}

\section{section1}
\section{section2}
\section{section3}
    \setcounter{subsection}{10}
    \subsection{subsectionA}
    \subsection{subsectionB}
    \subsection{subsectionC}
\end{document}



Solution depends on your setup. Please provide a full but minimal example that can generate the toc in the image. It is easy to fix, but we need to know your setup as it depends on the class and packages used

Use the tocloft package. It is build to help with this for the standardclasses. You are then looking for the lengths \cftsecnumwidth and \cftrsubsecnumwidth.

I still see the problem with tocloft

As I said you nedd to change the two lengths mentioned. The package does not automatically adjust it.

\addtolength\cftsecnumwidth{1em}
\addtolength\cftsubsecnumwidth{1em}. You many need to adjust the indents as well. It is al described in the tocloft manual

Since this is a standard class you can just use the tocloft package. Fx using
\usepackage{tocloft}

\addtolength\cftsecnumwidth{1em}
\addtolength\cftsubsecnumwidth{1em}
\addtolength\cftsubsecindent{1em}

The last line adjusts the indent of the subsection items to the still match up with the section elements above.

Could it be this package is not working with \usepackage{setspace}?

@MrI2C setspace messes with vertical space and have notthing to do with what we are doing here.

This is very easy using package tocbasic:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[dynnumwidth,dynindent]{tocline}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}% Reconfigure ToC entries for chapter … subparagraph to use the needed number width and indent

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{10} %use to adjust chapter number incase you don't include certain chapters
\setcounter{section}{10}
\setcounter{subsection}{10}

\section{section1}
\section{section2}
\section{section3}
    \setcounter{subsection}{10}
    \subsection{subsectionA}
    \subsection{subsectionB}
    \subsection{subsectionC}
\end{document}

You need at least three LaTeX runs to automatically get:

